# Multiples of some set has density

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, limsup-and-liminf

Nathanson gives a proof in *Elementary Methods in Number Theory* (Theorem 7.14) that, if a set $S$ of positive integers has
$$
\sum_{s\in S}\frac1s<+\infty
$$
then the set of positive multiples of $S$ has a natural density, i.e.,
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{|\{m\in M(S):\ m\le x\}|}{x}
$$
exists. I'd like to cite this result; does anyone know when it was first stated or proved? ("As far as I know Nathanson was first" would be a valid answer.)

Edit: Hall (*Sets of Multiples*) states that this is the best possible result in the sense that for any $\xi(x)\to+\infty$ there are sets $S$ with
$$
\sum_{s\in S,s\le x}\frac1s<\xi(x)
$$
for which the set of multiples of $S$ does not have a density. But I'm still looking for a reference on the original.

Comment: You mean $M(S)$ (or some other similar notation) rather than $S$ in your limit expression, right? What you have it the density of $S$, not the set of multiples of $S$.  Unless I'm confused.

Comment: An early mention: Erdos, On the Density of Some Sequences of Integers, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. Volume 54, Number 8 (1948), 685-692: "It is very easy to see that if $\sum \frac{1}{a_i}$ converges, then the sequence of $b$'s [the elements of the set of multiples of the set of $a$'s] has possesses a density." He does not prove this, but instead proves that a certain weaker condition is sufficient.

Comment: @MatthewConroy: Yes, thanks!